# NixOS using systemd-boot instead of grub, although it is disabled in nix config file

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader, nixos

I've installed NixOS 19 and as I want to dual boot with Windows 10, I need to use grub. And this is my bootloader configuration:

```
  # Boot loader
  boot.loader = {
    systemd-boot.enable = false;
    efi = {
      canTouchEfiVariables = true;
      efiSysMountPoint = "/boot";
    };
    grub = {
      devices = [ "nodev" ];
      enable = true;
      efiSupport = true;
      version = 2;
      useOSProber = true;
    };
  };
```

Even though I have disabled `systemd-boot`, it still shows `systemd-boot` and not `grub`!

### Rebuild result

`sudo nixos-rebuild --install-bootloader swich`:

```
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
updating GRUB 2 menu...
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
installing the GRUB 2 EFI boot loader into /boot...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
Installation finished. No error reported.
activating the configuration...
setting up /etc...
reloading user units for sddm...
reloading user units for aryan...
setting up tmpfiles
```

### /boot/EFI tree

`tree` of `/boot/EFI`:

```
/boot/EFI
├── BOOT
│   └── BOOTX64.EFI
├── Linux
├── nixos
│   ├── cp7c6zhwyipdd78r5d6ffm4p686bpyi3-initrd-linux-4.19.79-initrd.efi
│   ├── n3hx5p444cg1mnwqhicyha7z9d6f0h4h-linux-4.19.79-bzImage.efi
│   ├── p94zhzgyc1iccmp2jfr0nylk6bdr4zzf-initrd-linux-4.19.78-initrd.efi
│   └── s7zp6i6r73a0sri2fihmpnwbqrpsk8fs-linux-4.19.78-bzImage.efi
├── NixOS-boot
│   └── grubx64.efi
└── systemd
    └── systemd-bootx64.efi

5 directories, 7 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to switch from `Linux-bootloader` to `NixOS-bootloader` in BIOS settings.

Comment: I had the OPPOSITE issue, but of course the solution is exactly the same